# Help with some errors while trying to install Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 17.10

When I went to the terminal to have software updater give me the 18.04 message and typed `sudo update-manager -cd`. It responded with this message:

```
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(update-manager:7855): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

. I tried my second option which was `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`. Everything seemed fine until I realized it was for Ubuntu Server. Next I tried the previous command("update-manager -cd) and put it in alt f2 then software updater came up with not all updates can be installed. I checked my repositories and noticed they were all replaced with the bionic beaver ones. My questions are should I run a partial upgrade? Will I still get 18.04 if I do so? Is it okay to upgrade with bionic repositories? Is my system okay?

Comment: Your title is very misleading!

Comment: How? They're errors!

Comment: Title says install and the body says upgrade?

Comment: oh. Nevermind. Anyways, do you have any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Please complete your upgrade process!

Comment: I already figured it out myself before you posted that comment. I'm posting this comment on Bionic Beaver.

Comment: same problem is here

Comment: try to type `update-manager -cd` the command without sudo

Comment: I already fixed it, as I said in the comment before this